# populating php array variable is not working in godaddy server(php version 5.3.24) works perfectly in localhost

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to create an array by using xml file. but when i run the code in server (php version  5.3.24)  am getting an error. But tihis is working perfectly in localhost (php version 5.3.5)

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in
>   /home/content/61/10253461/html/crm/xmas/src.php on line 28

the 28th line is  $allowed[$i]=(int)$a->attributes()[1]; in the following code

```
function parcexml(){
$xml=simplexml_load_file("emaillist.xml");
$allowed=array();
$fname=array();
$femail=array();
$f1=array();
$f2=array();
 $i=0;
  foreach($xml->email as $a) {
    $allowed[$i]=(int)$a->attributes()[1];
    $fname[$i]=$a->attributes()[0];
    $femail[$i]=$xml->children()[$i];
    $i++;
}
}
```

please specify any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Function array deferencing is available only from PHP 5.4.0

So on your scenario do like this...

Instead of

```
$fname[$i]=$a->attributes()[0];
```

Do like

```
$v = $a->attributes();
$fname[$i] = $v[0];
```

[`Source`](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php)

Comment: Hi thanks.. this is working in server also.. but i dont know why my code is working on local server but not on online server.

Answer (score 2):

Change it to:

```
function parcexml(){
$xml=simplexml_load_file("emaillist.xml");
$allowed=array();
$fname=array();
$femail=array();
$f1=array();
$f2=array();
 $i=0;
  foreach($xml->email as $a) {
    $temp=(int)$a->attributes();
    $allowed[$i]=$temp[1];
    $fname[$i]=$temp[0];
    $temp=$xml->children();
    $femail[$i]=$temp[$i];
    $i++;
}
}
```